# copy on write using a pointer on integer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, copy-on-write

I try to implement copy on write using a pointer on integer. But I don't understand how to write the code. The idea is very clear in my head: when I use the default constructor, I create a new instance of the object (number of instances=1) and when I use the copy constructor, I increment the number of instances and make a shallow copy of the object.

```
    class Myclass
{
public:
    Myclass(const char * foo, int foo2) : foo(foo), foo2(foo2) 
    {
        (*ref)=1;
    }
    Myclass(const Myclass& rhs) :foo(rhs.foo),foo2(rhs.foo2) 
    {
        (*ref)++;
    }
    const char * foo;
    int foo2;
    int *ref;
};
```

I begin with C++ and the notion of pointer is completely news for me so I tried this. 
But I really don't understand why "ref" is still equal to 1 even if I create a copy of the object witht he copy constructor.

Comment: A pointer needs to be pointing to some object before you can de-reference it. Your `ref` pointer isn't.

Comment: Citizen is not MyClass, so you did not define that as the copy constructor.

Comment: Does it need to be pointing to an integer inside the class (a new attribut)?

Comment: `ref` should be a `static int ref`.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be a static int ref. The value cannot change then?

Comment: I may not understand the q. Do you want to increment ref every time a `Myclass` is created or just when the copy constructor is called? And, you can change a static member. It's not const.

Comment: I want to increment ref only when the copy constructor is called.

Comment: I create Myclass foo ("foo",10) and then Myclass foo2(foo). I want all ref to be equal to 2. Here only the ref of foo2 is equal to 2. The ref of foo is equal to 1. I think I need a pointer, no?

Comment: Only one of the 2 constructors will be called. Maybe you want to override operator=

Comment: Why overloading =? I want to implement shallow copy so that I could spare memory.

Comment: @rusol you'll eventually need to do both. Luckily, copy/swap idiom will work with what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand sorry :( Yes I will overload the = operator to create a shallow copy. But then I want to be able to create a deep copy when the object is modified. I don't understand how to use the reference counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default constructor needs to create a new reference count:

```
ref(new int(1))
```

And your copy constructor needs to make the new object end up with a pointer to the original object's reference count and to increment it (which you already do):

```
ref(rhs.ref)
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted Alan. Now I can create a deep copy constructor and implement lazy copy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding what you want but I'll try...

> I create Myclass foo ("foo",10) and then Myclass foo2(foo). **I want
>   all ref to be equal to 2**. Here only the ref of foo2 is equal to 2.
>   The ref of foo is equal to 1. I think I need a pointer, no?

This can be accomplished with a static variable:

```
class Myclass
{
public:
    Myclass(const char * foo, int foo2) : foo(foo), foo2(foo2) 
    {
        ref += 1;
        if (1 == ref) {}    // First ref, do something?
    }
    Myclass(const Myclass& rhs) :foo(rhs.foo),foo2(rhs.foo2) 
    {
        ref += 1;
    }
    ~Myclass()           // Decrement on delete
    {
        ref -= 1;
        if (0 == ref) {} // Last reference. Do something?
    }
    const char * foo;
    int foo2;
    static int ref;
};
int Myclass::ref = 0;   // Initialize to 0
```

Then....

```
Myclass foo("foo",10);             // ref becomes 1
Myclass foo2(foo);                 // ref becomes 2
Myclass *foo3 = new Myclass(foo);  // ref becomes 3
delete foo3;                       // ref becomes 2
```

Comment: Mhh the problem is that if I create another instance: Myclass foo3 ("foo",42). foo3.ref becomes 3. But I want it to be one.

Comment: So this is not what you want. You want to modify rhs.ref in the copy constructor but that's a const so you can't.

Comment: yes I think so, what is the solution then? It would be sad if it wasn't possible.